# How to convert asp:label to asp:texbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On the `page_load` event I am checking if the authorization is `Admin` or not.

If they are not in the `Admin` role then I have to change the available `asp:label` control to an `asp:textbox` control in the UI.

1. Is it be possible to dynamically convert/replace an `asp:label` control to an `asp:textbox` control?
2. If conversion/replacement is possible, then can I do it in the code behind instead of using jQuery?

```xml
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="Data">&nbsp;</asp:Label>
```

Comment: Why not have both controls on the page and hide the one (.Visible = false) on the one you do not need?

Comment: I agree whith @JeffSiver, and regarding conversion - You cannot turn one into another by casting, and I don't think there exists a converter in the .NET library, maybe there exists some 3rd party converter...

Comment: Thank you Jeff, Grx70. As this control is getting used for the multiple label to get display the text in one form only. I was wondering if i can convert it to the asp:textbox so while i have to save the changes of the label it will be the same id. But as Grx70 said it can't be converted. so i have used your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [MultiView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13165/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Tab-Control-Using-the-MultiView-c) in `ASP.NET` and have two `views`. You will have a `label` in one `view` and a `textbox` in the other.

```
if (user == "admin")
  multiView1.SetActiveView(adminView)
else
  multiView1.SetActiveView(userView)
```

The other solution would be to have a `label` and `textbox` and have the page hide them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could mark the TextBox control read-only for non-admins and style the textbox accordingly:

```
if !User.IsInRole("Administrators")
{
    TextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");  
    TextBox1.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);
}
```